# Getting a Manuscript Reviewed

Tags: reviews

I've had a few friends review my unpublished manuscript, and they were in my target market and quite knowledgeable in English. What are some good ways to get some more reviews, of a decent level in know-how of what makes a fiction book tick? I don't have much $. Eg. Specific ideas about clubs, any good website for authors to exchange, etc.

I've looked around the web and found some companies that cost about $250 for reviewing your structure, spelling, grammar, etc. but they seem to have limited credentials. I'm avoiding publishers too. The current q/a I've found on this website is limited to completed books getting publicity reviews.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What book review sites allow authors to send a copy of their books for reviews?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-book-review-sites-allow-authors-to-send-a-copy-of-their-books-for-reviews)

Comment: nope, it isn't a book yet, so book review people (eg. Goodreads.com) should not be seeing it yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me include the caveat that you get what you pay for. A review from a friend or a writing group member isn't going to be of same quality as a professional edit by a long shot.

[Writers Meetups](http://writers.meetup.com) can help you find a writing group in your area, as could Googling "writers club [your area]," as well as checking to see if there's a group at your local library or college.

The Writers Cafe website also has [a review forum](http://www.writerscafe.org/forum/Test-Out-Your-Work/) where you can request reviews. Unfortunately, it looks like there are a lot more people interested in getting their work reviewed than people doing reviews. So, if you do post something there, I would recommend doing reviews for other people so that they'll review your work.