# My Reviews for Free Books?

Tags: reviews

I would like to provide reviews in exchange for a free copy of the book. I have a great blog website with excellent SEO and social media following. I'm happy to provide the review on my website with a link to yours along with a review on GoodReads.com and Amazon.com. All reviews are 100% honest. I would not offer to do a review for a book genre that I know I am not interested in. That being said, I do have a variety of interests.

How can I identify writers or publishers to send me books to review?

Comment: Please check [What book review sites allow authors to send a copy of their books for reviews?][1]


  [1]: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-book-review-sites-allow-authors-to-send-a-copy-of-their-books-for-reviews

Comment: Lindsay, welcome to Writers. I'm not sure why someone voted to close this as off-topic; book reviewing is a type of writing and seems perfectly on-topic to me. However, I *can* see people wanting to close this as a list question: List questions will produce a potentially limitless list, a situation where it's not possible for anyone to write a canonical answer to the question. I've edited this so it's not asking for actual sites, and is asking how to identify sources of books to review.

Comment: @NeilFein I VTC because it sounded like self-promotion and a list question. Your edit makes it more answerable.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - Voting to close is a good thing; I wish more people did it so the mods can lay back more! People can also flag a question as spam if they think the question is self-promotional with no other merit. (Not the case here.)

Comment: Wow, tough crowd. My goodness.

Comment: @LindsayTampaBay, not meant to be; please bear with us.  Your question is a good one; list questions don't work well on SE, but changing to "how can I find" -- strategy, not specific outcome -- addresses that, and may bring in other factors that a list question would miss.  Anyway, welcome, and I hope we're able to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating an account at [LibraryThing](http://www.librarything.com/). They have an on going feature called [Early Reviewers](http://www.librarything.com/er/list) where someone can request an advance copy of a book in exchange for a review. You will be able to see a copy of the book cover along with a brief synopsis, so you can scroll through the pages and just request books that interest you. The books are listed for anywhere from a week to a month, and at the end of the listing, they randomly select the people who will receive a copy. For example, if 150 people request the book, but the author is only providing 30 copies, then LibraryThing will randomly select 30 people from the 150 who requested it.

For authors, you can take advantage of this to provide copies of your book (including e-books) in exchange for honest reviews. In my experience, I have found that anywhere from 6-15% of those requesting your book will actually follow through with the review. It's not a great return, but it's better than nothing!

Another option would be to visit any of the many writer's forums and post a message that you are accepting books to review. I would NOT recommend this approach. I know a few people who did this and ended up being inundated with requests. We writers can tend to be a greedy bunch, so be careful about opening those doors!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a while ago and I ended up finding, sites that help the promotion of new writers by getting their books reviewed by lots of reviewers. If you don't mind getting electronic copies of the book you can ask to review books at http://bookhubinc.wordpress.com/